# How can I modify the alignment of the Roman numerals in a list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

By default it aligns it to the right and I want to align it to the left

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you (a) load the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and (b) start the `enumerate` environment with the options `label=\Roman*.` (to obtain enumeration with uppercase-Roman numerals) and `align=left` (I trust you can figure out what this option does.)

The following screenshot shows two instances of `enumerate` environments -- the first *without*, the second *with* the option `align=left` in place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item Text 1
\item Text 2
\item Text 3
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
vs.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,align=left]
\item Text 1
\item Text 2
\item Text 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the text is misaligned, I don't know if there is a way to correct it.

Comment: @GuillermoLP -- How is the text misaligned?  I don't see that.

Comment: I detailed it in the comment below

Comment: @GuillermoLP - If you select `\huge` as the relative font size, you should also employ the list option `leftmargin=*`. Put differently, change `[label=\Roman*., align=left]` to `[label=\Roman*., align=left, leftmargin=*]`. See section 3, "Keys", of the user guide of the `enumitem` package for more information on these options.